# Difference between below syntax in unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ksh

I am new to Unix and learning the walk and talk of it. Lately I came across this syntax in my script which made me confused between the two:

```
G_DEST_DIR="/data/door1"

echo "mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}"
#&
mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}
```

According to my intel the above code will move the file(which is passed as an argument) and move it to the dest_dir

My question is what is the difference between

```
echo "mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}"
```

and

```
mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}
```

If I want to move a file which is passed as an argument how can I do that

Comment: You probably mean `echo` not `Echo`. And please read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: Sorry for the typo, edited it

Comment: Also, consider (for debugging purposes mostly) starting your script with e.g. `#!/bin/bash -vx` as its first line. But we don't have time to teach you all of bash scripting.

Comment: The above is just a sample code snippet I have jotted above. I have that in my actual scripts

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the BashGuide -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide -- is a much better reference than the ABS, particularly for beginners. In Freenode's #bash channel, we're constantly trying to help people un-learn bad habits they got from the ABS.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, i will refer that

Comment: The `&` on a line by itself would cause a syntax error in bash.

Comment: @mklement0 sorry forgot to comment that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `echo` command will print its arguments to the terminal. When calling your script with `myFile.txt` as the first argument, this line:

  ```
  echo "mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}"
  ```

  will print exactly this (**and it will not move the file**):

  > mv myFile.txt /data/door1
- The other line, not prefixed with `echo`:

  ```
  mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}
  ```

  will actually run the `mv` command and move your file to the `/data/door1` directory.

**Script analysis**

Let's analyse your script, line by line:

```
   1  G_DEST_DIR="/data/door1"
   2  
   3  echo "mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}"
   4  #&
   5  mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}
```

1. Declare a variable named `G_DEST_DIR` and put the string `/data/door1` into the  variable.
2. (empty line)
3. Just display a message to the user. The shell won't read the message; only the user (probably) will.
4. An ampersand `&` after a command means that the `echo` command will be [executed in background](http://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html). Your script will not wait for the command to end, it will move on to the next line. *(EDIT: line commented out after mklement0's comment.)*
5. Moves (`mv` command) the file given as the first argument (`$1`) to the directory named `/data/door1`.

**Bonus tip**

Putting `echo` before a command is a quick and effective way to dry-run the given command, that is, seeing what would be executed without `echo`.

Comment: I understand, but even when I use the command echo "mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}" it does move the file and also prints like you said. so i was confused

Comment: alright. I appreciate you time, and efforts to impart this. I understand it now clearly

Comment: `echo "blah blah"` will __print__ some message. It doesn't care what the message is: `echo` will just display it to the user.

Answer (score 3):

- `echo` = displays/prints a line of text
- `mv` = moves/renames the file

---

EDIT:
Example:
Let say $1 (first argument) is `old.txt`

- `echo "mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}"` will **print** out "mv old.txt /data/door1"
- `mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}` will **move** old.txt into directory /data/door1

Comment: True i agree, but in this case how are they different from each other

Comment: @Rahulsawant it isn't clear on its face how printing a line of text is different from moving a file?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: as in i understood the above, but in my script even when I use only echo "mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}" it does move the file and print it at the same time. on which i was confused why is it moving the file

Comment: `echo` only prints (it doesn't actually move the file); however, in your script you **also** have `mv` (which does the moving)

Comment: ... So if you don't want to move your file, then delete (or comment out by adding `#` to the front of) `mv $1 ${G_DEST_DIR}`

Answer (score 2):

`echo` does nothing put *print* the (one and only) argument to *stdout* - that its argument has the form of a shell command doesn't make a difference.

By contrast, the line that starts with `mv` performs an actual file move/rename command.

Prepending `echo` to a command is frequently used for *testing* to see what a command *would* do when executed, without actually executing (a potentially destructive/irreversible action).

As for the `mv` command: `$1` references the first argument passed to the script; to be safe, you should *double-quote* the reference, as should be done for variable references in general (`"$1"` and `"${G_DEST_DIR}"`).

Answer (score -2):

echo command displays anything written b/w "",but if u use any command and it will get eexecuted (if valid )first and then its o/p will be displayed.
so thats why your both command will move the data  to file but in first case line with echo the statement get esecuted with move command but it havo  no o/p so further it displays the mv then the filename as per given g_dest_dir variable.